# How to reference ng-recaptcha in feature module when import recptcha module in app.module.ts

Tags: angular

Compare to this setup [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-recaptcha?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts) (summarized below), I implemented ng-recaptcha in a  feature module of my app and it works as expected. But I want the import and provider in the `app.module.ts`, because I want to provide ng-recaptcha in other feature modules as well. If I move the imports and provider to `app.module.ts`, compiler throws:

> ERROR RuntimeError: NG01203: No value accessor for form control name:
> 'recaptcha'. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG01203...

sub-module/some.component.html

```
...
<form [formGroup]="myForm" method="post" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
...
  <re-captcha formControlName="recaptcha"></re-captcha>
...
</form>
...
```

sub-module/some.component.ts

```
myForm = this.fb.group({
    ...    
    recaptcha: [null, Validators.required]
  });
```

sub-module.modules.ts

```
import { RecaptchaFormsModule } from 'ng-recaptcha';
import { RecaptchaModule } from 'ng-recaptcha';
import { RECAPTCHA_SETTINGS, RecaptchaSettings } from 'ng-recaptcha';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    RecaptchaModule,
    RecaptchaFormsModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: RECAPTCHA_SETTINGS, useValue: { siteKey: environment.recaptcha.siteKey } as RecaptchaSettings }
...
```